# Span tag not always responding to width - changes between orgs

Tags: css, org

I have the following :

```
    SPAN.className{
      width: 30px;
      margin-top: 5px;
      display: block;
      float: left;
    }

    <span class="className">THIS IS SOME TEXT INSIDE A SPAN TAG</span>
```

This code snippet is from an older part of my application which I'm refactoring.  The `30px` width was added to this span tag by mistake and it should not be there. The text inside the span tag will always be wider than `30px`.

In all of our orgs bar one, the text overflows the span tag as if the width is not in affect, but in one org, the span tag is only `30px` wide and the text wraps.

Could someone possibly explain why the behaviour might be different from org to org?

The code base in each org is identical.

*There will be a bounty of at least 100pts on this in two days, I'll gladly award it to anyone that can explain it or at least help me understand it before then.*

Comment: Same page with values and same browsers when comparing? No other changes to that page or static resource css? The default behavior for just the code you posted should be to wrap the text. https://jsfiddle.net/d3say16u/

Comment: @CyberJus yes to all of that. Identical.

Comment: @CyberJus yes I know, that's why I do't understand why it's not wrapping everywhere. Only wrapping in one org.

Comment: I am not trying to give you the "did you try turning it off and on" response, but the logical result would be something different with the css. Did you try inspecting the element with Chrome or Firefox and comparing what styles are getting applied?

Comment: @CyberJus haha, no problem. I've tried everything I can think of short of altering the code : opening the same page in multiple browsers and inspecting every element and their parent and parent's parent and so on, logging in and out of the org. I'd like to understand it before I fix it.

Comment: Spring '15/Summer '15 org difference? Though seems unlikely.

Comment: @KeithC no, all still Spring 2015.